# Implementing a JavaScript API wrapper

Tags: javascript, design-patterns

Can anyone suggest a pattern that can be used for writing a JavaScript API **wrapper**, where there is no shared code between multiple implementations? The idea is to provide the client consumer with a single wrapping API for one of many possible APIs determined at runtime. APIs calls could be to objects/libraries already in the app environment, or web service calls.

The following bits of pseudo-code are two approaches I've considered:

## Monolithic Solution

```
var apiWrapper = {
      init: function() {
          // *runtime* context of which API to call
          this.context = App.getContext(); 
      },
      getName: function() {
           switch(context) {
             case a:
               return a.getDeviceName() // real api call
             case b:
               return b.deviceName // real api call
             etc...
           }
      // More methods ...
    }
}
```

**Pros**: Can maintain a consistent API for the library consumers.

**Cons**: Will result in a huge monolithic library, difficult to maintain.

## Module Solution

### init.js

```
// set apiWrapper to the correct implementation determined at runtime
require([App.getContext()], function(api) {
  var apiWrapper = api;
});
```

### module_a.js

```
// Implementation for API A
define(function() {
  var module = {
      getName: function() {
         return deviceA.getDeviceName();
       }
  };
  return module;
});
```

### module_b.js

```
// Implementation for API B
define(function() {
  var module = {
      getName: function() {
         // could also potentially be a web service call
         return deviceB.getName;
       }
  };
  return module;
});
```

**Pros**: More maintainable.

**Cons**: Developers need to take care that API remains consistent. Not particularly DRY.

This would be a case where something along the lines of an *Interface* would be useful, but as far as I'm aware there's no way to enforce a contract in Js.

Is there a best practice approach for this kind of problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Second approach is better because it is modular and you or a third person can easily extend it to incorporate other services. Point of "API remaining consistent" is not so valid because proper unit-tests you keep things consistent.

Second approach is also future proof because you don't know what unimaginable things you may have to do to implement say `getName` for service C, in that case it is better to have a separate module_c.js with all complications instead of spaghetti code in monolithic single module.

Need for real-interface IMO is not so important, a documented interface with unit-tests is enough.

Comment: Thanks Anurag, as both you and Flambino pointed out, having good test coverage here seems to be as good as it potentially gets.

Answer (score 4):

what a coincidence, someone is out there doing what i am also doing! recently, i have been delving into JS application patterns and i am exploring the modular pattern.

i started out with [this artice](http://addyosmani.com/largescalejavascript/) which has a lot of links that refer to other JS developers.

it would be better to go modular:

- mainly to avoid dependencies between two parts of a website
- though one could depend on the other, they are "loosely coupled".
- in order to build a site, it should work without breaking when you tear it apart
- also, you need to test out parts individually without using everything else
- easily swap out underlying libraries (jQuery, dojo, mootools etc.) without actually affecting the existing modules (since you are building our own API)
- in cases you need to change/upgrade your API (or when you change the underlying library), you only touch the API "backing" and not the API nor re-code the parts that are using it

here are links i have been through (vids mostly) that convey what the modular approach is all about and why use it:

- by [nicholas zakas](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vXjVFPosQHwby) - how to organize the API, libraries and modules
- by [addi osmani](http://addyosmani.com/scalable-javascript-videos/) - how and why modules
- by [Michael Mahemoff](http://softwareas.com/automagic-event-registration) - automatic module event (shout/listen) registration

Comment: Hello Joseph! I just wanted to say, that I also stumpled about this presentation from Addy Osmani. I especially liked the subject "library agnositc programming", no direct library calls in your large web application. And I already started generating a wrapper for my jQuery and Dojo. It would be nice that you would inform us about your further achievments! Wolfgang

Comment: Thanks for the links to the resources Joseph.

Answer (score 2):

I'd go the modular solution. Though there's no built-in way to enforce contracts, you can still decide on one, and then go TDD and build a test suite that tests the modules' interface compliance.

Your test suite then basically takes the role that compiling would in a language with explicit interfaces: If an interface is incorrectly implemented, it'll complain.